# The MS Access KB4484211 patch leaves ".laccdb" or ".ldb" files behind after the db are closed

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

After installing the MS Access KB4484211 patch users are reporting that ".laccdb" or ".ldb" files remain after the db is closed.

What is a best practice for ensuring these are auto-deleted?

NOTE: I only recently inherited these dbs to maintain.

Comment: Open Access and _force_ an update. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069553/here-we-go-again-ms-access-giving-file-already-in-use-error