# Here we go again. MS Access giving "file already in use" error

Tags: ms-access

This is seemingly related from the recent kerfuffle with Microsoft Access that is detailed in [This question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365001/microsoft-access-dbengine-opendatabase-breaks-for-network-paths-error-3050/70599779#70599779)

That problem was fixed by a recent update to Office 365 round about mid January.

Now it seems to be cropping up again with one user in particular.  Other users are not affected.

This user (user A) cannot get in to the database if anyone else is already in the database.  He gets the "file is already in use error".  If user A gets into the DB first, other users get that error.  If, however, a different user gets into the database first, others are able to get into it just fine.

When the Lockfile (*.laccdb) is created under normal circumstances, it is usually about 1k in size and if I open the lockfile with Notepad I can identify the user that is in the DB.  When User A gets into the database, a lockfile appears, but it is 0k in size and is apparently empty.  this lockfile will persist after he gets out of the db, and has to be manually deleted about half the time before anyone else can use it.

I'm scheduling time to work with User A to get more details of what the version of Office 365 and what updates he has, and see if they differ from the other users.

The database in question is a split database with the front end for the users being a .accdr file on the user's local machine.  The back end is hosted on a large shared drive for the entire facility (approx 1000 users on the G drive, however not everyone has access to the same folders).  All users have read/write permission to the shared drive.  This same database has been in use like this for about 3 years and when the office moved to Office 365, there were no problems.  All of the users on this DB are running Windows 7.  I do not have the ability at this time to move the back end to a dedicated server, and our IT department has been moved off site and for the most part, out of country and outsourced.

Is there anything I should be watching for?  Thanks for any help ya'll might be able to provide.

Comment: The bug came back and was fixed again. Check your build: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-is-unable-to-close-and-leaves-lockfile-active-b2dce32b-b8b0-41f1-ba40-7876e524d9da

Comment: @Andre thanks for the heads up!  much appreciated.